# Python error code 1

Tags: python, linux, bots, raspbian

I'm attempting to use a [discord bot](https://github.com/Twentysix26/Red-DiscordBot/wiki/Installing-on-Linux) on my [raspberry pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). I am running the most resent version of raspbian installed via the noobs installer. I'm trying to do this: `sudo pip3.5 install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@async` But I get this error:

```
"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yBdLez/aiohttp/".
```

The full error is here:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build-yBdLez/aiohttp/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
   raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+")
RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+
```

From what i can tell it's saying that my python is not properly updated. However to my knowledge it is already fully updated to the most recent version and when I do :

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

it says "Python is already the newest version", so I don't understand what is wrong here. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Debian-derived distributions preserve the `python` command for Python 2.x.  Try `python3 setup.py egg_info`.  If that gives you "command not found" or similar, `sudo apt-get install python3`.

Comment: have you tried installing without `@async`?

Comment: zwol when i did the "python 3 setup.py egg_info i got this: "python3 can't open file "setup.py: [Error 2] No such file or directory" so i ussemed this is what you meant by command not found, however when i did the "sudo apt-get install python3" i get "python3 is already the newest version". So do you have any other ideas? xD

Comment: i realize now that you weren't running setup.py _yourself_; it was run for you by the `pip3.5` command.  This is a bug in the package you are trying to install; it doesn't understand that it should be running `python3` instead of `python`.  File a bug report with the authors of "discord bot".

Comment: Zwol, so is there nothing else i can do? I just have to wait for them to do something? or is there another method i could use to install it?